# Should I include specialization or focus courses during my studies in my CV?

Tags: resume

I am a student of mathematics with an interest in computer science/numerical analysis.

Should I specify in my resume the courses in which I emphasized and focused the most during my studies? (The courses that interest me more than just studying to pass the course)

Quick example:

**Bachelor of Science, Department of Mathematics**

Focus on:
*Computability Theory, Calculus, Cryptography, Information Theory etc...*

---

Or is it more appropriate to include the above lessons in a separate category as:

**Research Interests**

*Computability Theory etc.*

Comment: this is not indicated in the question. If this is important, consider [edit]ing to expand on details of that

Comment: Hi Nickolas. I am a tech recruiter at a data analytics company so feel like I can help out here. The answer is; it depends. Quite frankly, when someone has several years of commercial experience then I am not going to pay too much attention to their study focus. The one exception is if I see someone with <5 years experience and has a PHD. For others - I would only include extra study details if it will really help you. Eg. You don't have work experience and your degree looks generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Yes, you should provide all information on whatever you are good at. Why?

1. Employers wants to know the person who is going to join the team. What are his/her interests, achievements, extra curricular, hobbies etc.
2. You have to express (CV is only one way to express before face to face interview)that I am not just an employee who will take salary and go home. I am also a mathematics genius, swimmer, badminton champ, die hard fan of tom cruise blah blah.
3. They want to assure a best suitable place for you in the company. May be you applied for "Executive" position but they see that you have good skills they post you as "Sr Executive"
4. It makes your CV attractive and gives you stand out position among other candidates, those have same education, but lesser skills than you.

If you talk about above examples, I would choose "Focus on:" because "Research Interest" is too subtle to express that you are really good at it. For example you and Mr X, both has worked on those extra skills but "X" has only interest and you worked with all focus.

Comment: But I would only include "focus on" for things you had more than one class in. To me it implies you did more in depth work than just one class. For instnace just many people end up with a statistics class at some point (many majors require it.) but someone who focused on it might have 3-4 or more.

Comment: @HLGEM When I write "focus on/specialization" I mean courses that interest me and work more in depth other than just studying to pass.

Comment: Yes but that is NOT how an employer would interpet that phrase. I would expect more classes and I would consider you to be lying on your resume (and thus ineligible for hire) if I found out you only had one.  Perhaps you might want to use a different phrase such as "coursework included". that indicates what classes you you took and by specifying some, it indicates you havea an interest in those areas.